# JPA: should I store a BLOB in the same table with fetch Lazy or should I store it to another table and fetch lazy the one to one relationship

Tags: java, jpa, blob

I have a table `Image` that hold the image information. I also want to store the image itself. So should I

1.Store the Blob in the same image table and fetch it lazy as below

```
@Basic(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Lob
@Column(name = "IMAGE_BLOB", length=100000)    //This will generate MEDIUMBLOB
private byte[] imageBlob;
```

**Or**

2.Create a another table `ImageBlob` with `OneToOne` relationship with `Image`, and fetch lazy the relationship

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "image", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private ImageBlob imageBlob;
```

Are these two technique the same in term of performance?

Comment: Do as the first implementation. It will not affect if you are fetching lazily. You could write another method where it returns based on row unique id if BLOB should be returned.

Comment: Please accept or close the question.

Comment: @Phani: Just to confirm my understand about fetch lazy, the blob will not be `SELECT`, correct Phani? It will only be `SELECT`, once I start access the blob variable itself via getter. Is my understand there correct, Phani?

Comment: you are right.Please make sure it's not part of select.

Comment: @Phani: How do I make sure if it is not part of the SELECT, Phani. I cannot seems to find a way to see the SELECT statement generate by JPA.

Comment: I mean to say make sure you mark with annotation as lazy.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the first does not work with Hibernate and EclipseLink as JPA providers. LAZY is a hint for the provider, these will load eagerly without reporting an error or warning.

OneToOne association will be lazy only if class weaving is enabled, otherwise it will not help either.

I have done it using a completely separate table called LazyBlob, with attributes "entity" and "id", and wrote an utility class to fetch lob lazily from this table.

Comment: LAZY on a basic does work with EclipseLink (using weaving).  But a separate table is normally better for large LOBs.

Comment: @James LAZY does *sort of work* with Eclipselink weaving. At least with Eclipselink 2.3.1, it will work for simple queries, but if you join fetch to another table the LOB will be fetched eagerly. I have had to work around this limitation in some applications.

Comment: That's why I used the approach in answer. As long as LAZY is a hint, you never know, when it will stop working. That is not a problem, if the file is small, but it is, if it is large and only in small fraction of cases needed.

Answer (score 3):

Both should result in the same performance, but I would recommend the second for large blobs.

Databases can be finicky with blobs, and it is better to have them isolated to their own object.  This will give you more control over the blob.